# success Message not Displaying

Tags: php

I have made one form on WP-admin side when i approved and reject the form working well but not sure why I'm not able to show my success Message on right place.

if i echo it working well but not right place. i want to show after my h2 tag below my codes.

```
<?php 
// Add a new menu item in the WordPress admin menu
function add_custom_menu_item() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Contracts Data',        // Page title
        'Contracts Data',        // Menu title
        'manage_options',        // Capability required
        'contracts-data',        // Menu slug
        'display_custom_menu'    // Callback function to display page content
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_menu_item');

/// Display custom admin page
function display_custom_menu() {
    $success_message = '';
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php
        // Display success or error message
     if (!empty($success_message)) {
         echo '<div class="success-message">' . $success_message . '</div>';
     }
     ?>
        <h2>Contracts Data</h2>
        <table class="wp-list-table widefat striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>SL</th>
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Order Status</th>
                    <th>User Email</th>
                    <th>Contract File</th>
                    <th>Contract Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                global $wpdb;
                $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'contracts';
                $contracts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name", ARRAY_A);
                $cont=1;
                foreach ($contracts as $contract) {
                    $order = wc_get_order( $contract['order_number'] );
                    $order_status = $order ? $order->get_status() : 'Order not found';
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $cont++ . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>{$contract['order_number']}</td>";
                    echo "<td>{$order_status}</td>";
                    echo "<td>{$contract['user_email']}</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='" . plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . "{$contract['contract_file']}' target='_blank'>Download</a></td>";
                    echo "<td>{$contract['status']}</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='order_id' value='{$contract['order_number']}'>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='user_email' value='{$contract['user_email']}'>";
                if($contract['status']=='approved'){
                    echo "<button type='submit' name='action' value='reject' class='btn btn-danger'>Reject</button>";
                } else{
                    echo "<button type='submit'name='action' value='approved' class='btn btn-success'>Approve</button>";
                }
                    echo "</form>";
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function update_contract_status( $order_id, $status ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'contracts';
    
    $wpdb->update(
        $table_name,
        array( 'status' => $status ),
        array( 'order_number' => $order_id ),
        array( '%s' ),
        array( '%d' )
    );
}
// Handle form submission
function handle_contract_submission_app() {
    if( isset( $_POST['order_id'] ) && isset( $_POST['action'] ) ) {
        $order_id = intval( $_POST['order_id'] );
        $action = $_POST['action'];
       

        if ( $action === 'approved' ) {
            // Update contract status in the contract table
            update_contract_status( $order_id, 'approved' );
            $success_message = 'Contract status updated to Approved successfully!';
           
        } elseif ( $action === 'reject' ) {
            update_contract_status( $order_id, 'rejected' );
            $success_message = 'Contract status updated to Rejected successfully!';
            //echo '<div class="success-message">Contract status updated to Rejected successfully!</div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'handle_contract_submission_app');
```

Help Me to find my error
thanks

Comment: "i want to show after my h2 tag below my codes" -- You've put it *above* the `<h2>` tag; move the `<?php {success message code} ?>` to where you want it in the HTML. Also, you're setting `$success_message=''` and then not setting it to anything else, so when the display code happens, your `$success_message` is still empty.

Comment: should i remove this--  ```$success_message=''```

Comment: If you want to display a message there, you'll need to set `$success_message` to *something*. It's not pre-populated, and currently your code is setting it to `''`, which is empty.

Comment: HI, i made this because if i don't have message then not show error. So, should i avoid this line?